# JUL logging.properties and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, glassfish-3, java.util.logging

I'm trying to get Hibernate to log parameter values. 
I'm using Netbeans and deploying the resulting WAR file to Glassfish on an Ubuntu box. 
I'm using java util logging (rather than log4j etc) because I haven't used it before and want to see how it compares.

I've set the hibernate.show_sql property to true in persistence.xml and yes, I can see the SQL coming out in the logs (INFO level). However, to see the param values being used in the SQL, I believe I need to change the log level for Hibernate to TRACE (or at least DEBUG) whereas my app seems to be set to INFO level.

I understand that logging.properties is the place to do it, but the docs all seem to point to configuring that in the JRE, which would be system-wide.

My question is... can I put logging.properties somewhere in my application instead, so different apps on the same appserver can have different logging configurations?

And, given that (from what I read) Hibernate uses common logging, will I get this information at all, since I am using JUL rather than common logging?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the properties file at the root of classpath in your application. For web applications one of the place is WEB-INF/classes

If you enable the TRACE level you would be able to see the TRACE statements like these

```
insert into table (name, id) values (?, ?)
.........................

binding '1' to parameter: 2
```

However this is not probably what you want. If you want that the sql itself should show the included bound parameter, then you can use P6Spy library. Setting up P6Spy is very easy. You can see how to set it [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/).

Once you set it up you can see the sql in the logs

```
insert into grouptable (name, id) values ('Name', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Shailendra, I've got it working. Just had to find the correct logging.properties file. My bundled Netbeans/Glassfish instance's file was in C:\Users\richard\.netbeans\7.1.1\config\GF3\domain1\config. I set org.hibernate.level=FINEST (seems to correspond to TRACE) and I now get all the hibernate trace info. I'm going to try P6Spy now, that sounds invaluable. Thanks for the tip